# Regex to match everything except this regex

Tags: regex

I think this is a simple thing for a lot of you, but I have a very limited knowlegde of regex at the moment. I want to match everything except a double digit number in a string.

For example:

**TEST**22**KLO4567**

**QE**45**C2C**

**LOP**10**G7G400**

Now I found out the regex to match the double digit numbers:
\d{2}

Which matches the following:

TEST**22**KLO4567

QE**45**C2C

LOP**10**G7G400

Now it seems to me that it would be fairly easy to turn that regex around to match everything BUT "\d{2}". I searched a lot but I can't seem to get it done. I hope someone here can help.

Comment: Am I right that that you want to match everything but the **first** double digit number?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure. I use it in Channable, which is a web-based feed management tool. So my guess is Javascript.

Comment: Do all strings have one 2-digit occurrence or could it be more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only works if your regex engine supports look behinds:

```
^.+?(?=\d{2})|(?<=\d{2}).+$
```

Explanation:

The `|` separates two cases where this would match:

- ^.+?(?=\d{2})

This matches everything from the start of the string (`^`) until `\d{2}` is encountered.

- (?<=\d{2}).+$

This matches the end of the string, from the place just after two digits.

If your regex engine doesn't support look behinds (JavaScript for example), I don't think it is possible using a pure regex solution.

You can match the first part:

```
^.+?(?=\d{2})
```

Then get where the match ends, add 2 to that number, and get the substring from that index.

Comment: What about `QE4544C2C`?

Comment: @revo I think the assumption here is all strings will have a two digit number, no?

Comment: Yes, all the strings have a two digit number!

Comment: I tried to read such a statement from OP but couldn't. How about `QE45C2C22A`?

Comment: @revo I know it's kind of ambiguous here. But to not match the latter number I can just make the first case greedy `^.+(?=\d{2})|(?<=\d{2}).+$`. It's a simple fix.

Comment: I was thinking about three separate matches (`QE`, `C2C` and `A`).

Comment: @user3457337 What is supposed to happen with `QE45C2C22A`?

Comment: Sorry, that might not have been clear in my first statement. The strings only contain one double digit number.

Answer (score 1):

You are right rejecting a search in regex is usually rather tricky.

In your case I think you want to have `[^\d{2}]`, however, this is tricky as your other strings also contain two digits so your regex using it won't select them.

I would go with this regex (using `PCRE 8.36` but should work also in others):

`\*{2}\w*\*{2}`

Explanation:

`\*{2}` .... matches "*" literally exactly two times
`\w*`   .... matches "word character" zero or unlimited times

Answer (score 0):

Found one regex pretty straightforward :

```
^(.*?[^\d])\d{2}([^\d].*?)$
```

Explanations :

- ^ : matches the beginnning of a line
- (.*?[^\d]) : matches and catches the first part before the two numbers. It can contain anything (.*?) but needs to end with something different  to a number ([^\d]) so we ensure that there is only 2 numbers in the middle
- \d{2} : is the part you found yourself
- ([^\d].*?) : is the symetric of (.*?[^\d]) : begins with something different from a number ([^\d]) and matches anything next.
- $ : up to the end of the line.

To test this reges you can use this [link](https://regex101.com/r/Np8y9V/1)

It will match the first occurence of double digit, but because OP said there was only one it does the job correctly. I expect it to work with every regex engine as nothing too complex is used.