# Getting what's left after removing regex match

Tags: sql, regex, posix, db2-400

Context is SQL on the AS/400 (IBM i)

My goal is to end up with two values: a string determined by a regex I already have, and then everything else in the source string with the result of the regex removed and the gap (if any) closed up.

Here's the SQL:

```
select HAD1,                                                   
 regexp_substr(HAD1,'\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\s[\dA-Z]{1,}'),
 regexp_substr(HAD1,'**eventual_regex_goes_here**')                
from ECH                                                       
where regexp_like(HAD1,'\bGATE')
```

And the desired result:

```
Ship To                              REGEXP_SUBSTR     REGEXP_SUBSTR       
Address                                                                 
D2 COMPOUND, GATE 11                 GATE 11           D2 COMPOUND,  
2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE                   -                 2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE  
ASHBURTON FITTINGS  GATE 2           GATE 2            ASHBURTON FITTINGS
BRIERLY RD, GATE A, RIVER SIDE       GATE A            BRIERLY RD, , RIVER SIDE  
GATE 16, 37 KENEPURU DRIVE           GATE 16           , 37 KENEPURU DRIVE
```

If the second expression could take the commas out too that would be great, but it's not required. The remaining string will be put through other (non-regex) processing to remove extraneous elements (phone numbers, comments, punctuation, etc.)

The closest of the posts suggested by the board software was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482125/regex-to-match-everything-except-this-regex), which gave the following string:

```
^.+?(?=\d{2})|(?<=\d{2}).+$
```

So, first I tried putting my whole expression in place of both occurrences of `\d{2}` and found that this (unsurprisingly) would not process. Then I went back to a more basic test and tried to build up from there.

Let's try just the word GATE as a constant, plus a couple of boundaries ( because deep down I'm still just a child, and you know what they say: "Children need boundaries").

```
select had1,                                                   
 regexp_substr(HAD1,'\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\s[\dA-Z]{1,}'),
 regexp_substr(HAD1,'^.+?(?=\bGATE\b)|(?<=\bGATE\b).+$')               
from ech                                                       
where regexp_like(HAD1,'\bGATE')
```

Result:

```
Ship To                                   REGEXP_SUBSTR     REGEXP_SUBSTR                 
Address                                                                                   
GATE 3, CNR QUARRY ROAD                   GATE 3             3, CNR QUARRY ROAD           
ASHBURTON FITTINGS  GATE 2                GATE 2            ASHBURTON FITTINGS            
GATE 6, HELLABYS ROAD                     GATE 6             6, HELLABYS ROAD             
GATE 3, 548 PAKAKARIKI HILL               GATE 3             3, 548 PAKAKARIKI HILL       
GATE 5 - FLIGHTYS COMPOUND                GATE 5             5 - FLIGHTYS COMPOUND        
GATE 3 - 548 PAEKAKARIKI HILL ROAD        GATE 3             3 - 548 PAEKAKARIKI HILL ROAD
GATE 14 - TAKAPU COMPOUND                 GATE 14            14 - TAKAPU COMPOUND         
35 GATEWAY DRIVE                          -                 -                             
GATE 6                                    GATE 6             6                            
TAKAPU ROAD,GATE 20,SH1                   GATE 20            TAKAPU ROAD,
```

This is looking promising, keeping in mind that I'm not using the full expression for the second result column. But there is already one thing wrong.

In the second and last row there should be more data, '2' and ',SH1', respectively. And the string '35 GATEWAY DRIVE' should be in the last column. I want **everything** except what the expression finds (which is just the whole word GATE at the moment, remember).

It seems it can return the remaining text from one side or other of the removed text, but not both, and not all the remaining text if nothing is found to remove. So there's no point in my pressing on with adding in more sophistication to include the gate number until I understand why I'm not getting all the text that is not **GATE**. Therefore I'll pause here and ask for help.

Comment: It might be easier to write a small parser in your programming language of choice.

Comment: It may well turn out that way, but a project with lots of text/string manipulation (cleaning up ship-to addresses) seemed like a good chance to get into regex, which has been available on the AS/400 (as I still call it) for a couple of years now.
Besides, If I give up now, what kind of man would I be? People would spit at me on the street, and elderly ladies would give me white feathers. No, I cannot bring that shame on myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
with data (s) as (values
('D2 COMPOUND, GATE 11'), 
('2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE'),
('ASHBURTON FITTINGS  GATE 2'),
('BRIERLY RD, GATE A, RIVER SIDE'),
('GATE 16, 37 KENEPURU DRIVE')
) 
select s,
       regexp_substr(s,' ?(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS) '),
       replace(regexp_replace(s,' ?(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS) ',''),',',' ')
from   data
```

Result:

```
D2 COMPOUND, GATE 11             GATE   D2 COMPOUND 11
2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE                 -    2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE
ASHBURTON FITTINGS  GATE 2       GATE   ASHBURTON FITTINGS 2
BRIERLY RD, GATE A, RIVER SIDE   GATE   BRIERLY RD A  RIVER SIDE
GATE 16, 37 KENEPURU DRIVE       GATE   16  37 KENEPURU DRIVE
```

Comment: Well, that's just blooming marvellous. How did I not notice that there was a regexp_replace() function?  I was too focussed on the idea of substringing. Thanks for grabbing me by the lapels and giving me a good shake.

Answer (score 0):

I've already selected the correct answer kindly supplied by user2398621.

However, for those playing at home, here is the full-fat nearly-application-ready answer in the context of the data it will be applied to. Comments are bracketed like /* this */

```
select distinct HAD1 ,                                              
regexp_substr(HAD1 ,'\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\s[\dA-Z]{1,}'),     
trim(     /* remove leading/trailing blanks from REPLACE func */    
replace(   /* replace commas  */                                    
 replace(   /* replace slashes */                                   
  replace(   /* replace dashes  */                                  
   regexp_replace(HAD1 ,'\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\s[\dA-Z]{1,}',  
                  '')  /* replace extra address detail with null */ 
          ,'-',' ')                                                 
         ,'/',' ')                                                  
        ,',',' ')                                                   
     )                                                              
from ECH                                                            
where regexp_like(HAD1 ,'\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\b')             
  and length(trim(HAD1 )) > 12   /* show only longish addresses in sample */
```

Sample GATE entries

```
Ship To                                   REGEXP_SUBSTR    REGEXP_REPLACE    
Address                                                                       
GATE 6 52 MAHIA ROAD                      GATE 6           52 MAHIA ROAD        
ASHBURTON FITTINGS  GATE 2                GATE 2           ASHBURTON FITTINGS   
FIRST GATE AFTER THE ROUNDABOUT           GATE AFTER       FIRST  THE ROUNDABOUT
GATE 2,  61-63 NORMANBY ROAD              GATE 2           61 63 NORMANBY ROAD  
GATE 7, OFF MORRING STREET                GATE 7           OFF MORRING STREET   
GATE 7 OFF MORRIN STREET                  GATE 7           OFF MORRIN STREET    
GATE 6 SUBSTATION ROAD                    GATE 6           SUBSTATION ROAD      
VIA GATE 4, BUILDING 108                  GATE 4           VIA   BUILDING 108
```

Sample LEVEL entries (Note that 1st line blank REGEXP_REPLACE is correct as both LEVEL and UNIT (and their numbers) have been removed)

```
Ship To                                   REGEXP_SUBSTR    REGEXP_REPLACE
Address                                                          
LEVEL 2  UNIT 16                          LEVEL 2                                      
TRANSPOWER HOUSE - LEVEL 8                LEVEL 8          TRANSPOWER HOUSE             
LEVEL 3/27 NAPIER STREET                  LEVEL 3          27 NAPIER STREET             
LEVEL 2 GRAHAM STREET SERVICE CENTRE      LEVEL 2          GRAHAM STREET SERVICE CENTRE 
LEVEL 1 - MATT WILES                      LEVEL 1          MATT WILES                   
ANZ CENTRE, LEVEL 2                       LEVEL 2          ANZ CENTRE
```

Sample DOOR entries

```
Ship To                                   REGEXP_SUBSTR   REGEXP_REPLACE
Address                                                               
NEXT DOOR TO 201                          DOOR TO         NEXT  201    
WAREHOUSE DOOR A                          DOOR A          WAREHOUSE    
DOOR 11 ( WAREHOUSE)                      DOOR 11         ( WAREHOUSE) 
DOOR 11 (WAREHOUSE)                       DOOR 11         (WAREHOUSE)
```

Sample UNIT entries

```
Ship To                                   REGEXP_SUBSTR   REGEXP_REPLACE
Address                                                               
UNIT B 11 LANGSTONE LANE                  UNIT B          11 LANGSTONE LANE   
26 BELFAST ROAD UNIT 1                    UNIT 1          26 BELFAST ROAD     
UNIT C 589 TERMAINE AVE                   UNIT C          589 TERMAINE AVE  
UNIT 1, 3 HENRY ROSE PLACE                UNIT 1          3 HENRY ROSE PLACE
UNIT 1/12 ANVIL ROAD                      UNIT 1          12 ANVIL ROAD     
UNIT D1, 269A MT SMART ROAD               UNIT D1         269A MT SMART ROAD
```

You will notice that there still a few anomalies, even in this small sample - for instance sometimes removing the text selected by the expression leaves a nonsensical remainder, sometimes we need the dash that was removed, and so on, but I'll take manually revising 5% over manually revising 95% of the cases that need attention.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already marked an answer correct, but here is one without all those `replace`s. The difference is I have selected spaces and comma's on either side of the initial REGEX to replace with a single blank, then if that blank leads or trails the string, I trim it off like this:

```
CREATE TABLE strtest
  (string   varchar(255));

INSERT INTO strtest
VALUES ('D2 COMPOUND, GATE 11'),
       ('2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE'),
       ('ASHBURN FITTINGS  GATE 2'),
       ('BRIERLY RD, GATE A, RIVER SIDE'),
       ('GATE 16, 37 KENEPURU DRIVE')

select STRING,                                                   
       regexp_substr(STRING,'\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\s[\dA-Z]{1,}'),
       TRIM(regexp_REPLACE(STRING,'[ ,/-]*\b(GATE|LEVEL|DOOR|UNITS?)\s[\dA-Z]{1,}[ ,/-]*', ' '))
  from STRTEST                                                       
  where regexp_like(STRING,'\bGATE')
```

```
|STRING                                 |REGEXP_SUBSTR  |REGEX_REPLACE           |
|---------------------------------------|---------------|------------------------|
|D2 COMPOUND, GATE 11                   |GATE 11        |D2 COMPOUND             |
|2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE                     |               |2/22 GATEWAY DRIVE      |
|ASHBURN FITTINGS  GATE 2               |GATE 2         |ASHBURN FITTINGS        |
|BRIERLY RD, GATE A, RIVER SIDE         |GATE A         |BRIERLY RD RIVER SIDE   |
|GATE 16, 37 KENEPURU DRIVE             |GATE 16        |37 KENEPURU DRIVE       |
|LEVEL 3/27 NAPIER STREET               |LEVEL 3        |27 NAPIER STREET        |
|LEVEL 1 - MATT WILES                   |LEVEL 1        |MATT WILES              |
```

The magic is in the `[ ,]*` expressions I tacked on to the the beginning and end of the REGEXP. If you want to get dashes and slashes as well, just make that `[ -,/]*`.

You still have those troublesome `DOOR TO` and `GATE AFTER` entries, but they are minimal, and you can likely correct them afterwards.

Comment: "...here is one without all those replaces"  
Actually I was wondering about whether those could be dealt with within the regex, but I didn't think I could possibly be that lucky - I had achieved so much already.  
Thanks for adding real value to the solution.

Comment: p.s. you were in time before I actually implemented the code so your refinement will make it into the final program, and make me look smarter than I am (or at least less stupid).